# Best place to create new instance of class in C#

Tags: c#, class, instance

What is difference between these codes
1.

```
Public class class1()
{ ... }

Public class Main()
{
   public void method()
   {
      class1 k = new class1;     <---
      ...
   }
}
```

2.

```
Public class class1()
{ ... }

Public class Main()
{
   class1 k = new class1;      <---

   public void method()
   {
      k.use();
      ...
   }
}
```

Where is better place to create instance of a class, at root of second class or in each method and function that need class1?

Comment: That would depend on wether you need it after you exit the method.

Comment: There is one commonality, though - neither code snipped would compile

Comment: in first example your instance k1 will be available to everything in your class. and will stay alive as long as Program does or explicitly given a null value. 
the second example would create the instance k1 and kill it when the scope of the method ends.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends a lot from how you are going to use the object.

Is it a disposable resource that must be instantiated and disposed every time you use it (thinking of a db connection)? Then instantiating in the method is the safest way.

If the container object is meant to be quickly disposed after usage, and you want to use the dependence in more than one method, then instantiating it in the constructor or directly in the field could be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is not to create new instance in your code but use dependency injection. Best to use some interface or abstract class. This way you don't rely on concrete implementation and your code is more testable because you can controll what is `passedThroughConstructor`. While writing code for `SomeOne` class you do not care about where `SomeTwo` is created, you show that your `SomeOne` depends on it and cannot be created without it.

```
public class SomeOne{

ISomeTwo _forInternalUse;
  public SomeOne(ISomeTwo passedThroughConstructor){
     _forInternalUse = passedThroughConstructor;
  }

  public void SomeOtherMethod(){
      _forInternalUse.DoStuff();
   }
}
```